# MySQL multiple table SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three tables:

```
Table(attribute1, attribute2...);    
---------------------------------
Users(iduser, username)    
Link(idlink, title, userid)    
Comment(idcomment, content, linkid, userid)
```

How to select:
Link title, with corresponding username and number of comments?

```
I'm currently doing like this:
Q1-Select links (SELECT * FROM `links`)
Q2-Extract usernames from previous query(Q1) - (SELECT username FROM `user` WHERE iduser=Q1.userid
Q3-Extract number of comments from Q1 by id (SELECT COUNT(*) as comments FROM `comment` WHERE linkid='Q1.idlink')
```

I believe we can do this in much more optimized way. I got idea how to get Link with corresponding username but I got stuck when I need to count comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT iduser, username, Link.title, COUNT(idcomment)
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Link ON (iduser = userid)
LEFT JOIN Comment ON (linkid = idlink)
GROUP BY iduser, idlink
```

Note that your Comment table is somewhat badly designed - the 'userid' field is not necessary, and can actually lead to situation where you've got a cross-linked record. e.g. a Comment belonging to user A might could be linked to a Link record belonging to user B.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted! How Am I supposed to construct comment then? I'm selecting userid from comment later when I'm selecting comments. Do you mean I just need to rename column name?

Comment: Depends on your usage. Maybe you only allow ONE of linkid or userid to be set, so a single comment can only ever be attached to a user OR a link, but not both.

Comment: I think you have both missed the point here. A comment is made by one user about one link.

Comment: Comment is made by user on specific link, user can comment more than once, link is made by user, user can make more links.

Comment: Then the linkage should be user->link->comment - one single foreign key pointing back at the immediate "ancestor" table. While there's nothing really WRONG with how you've done it (it saves a step trying to get info  on a user who left a comment, by eliminating having to join in the link table), it does allow mis-attribution.

Comment: Thanks Marc B, I'll have to learn more about database design and normalization.

Comment: @MarcB is wrong in this case.  The two FK relationships are separate.  His structure is correct.  A link is created by one user.  A comment is made by one user in relation to one link.

Comment: @nnichols: good point. I hadn't even considered that. So yeah, this structure is actually ok. user1188570- sorry, misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to get into the habit of putting the fields you want into both the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses, that way it won't come as such a shock when you have to use an RDBMS that insists on it.

```
SELECT
    `l`.`idlink`,
    `l`.`title`,
    `u`.`username`,
    COUNT(`c`,`idcomment`) AS `comment_count`
FROM `links` `l`
INNER JOIN `users` `u`
    ON `l`.`userid` = `u`.`iduser`
LEFT JOIN `comments` `c`
    ON `l`.`idlink` = `c`.`linkid`
GROUP BY
    `l`.`idlink`,
    `l`.`title`,
    `u`.`username`
```

Comment: "It is good practice to get into the habit of putting the fields you want into both the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses, that way it won't come as such a shock when you have to use an RDBMS that insists on it." --- no it is not. None of RDBMS **requires** to put all the group by columns to the select. You can even select none of the group by fields but go with just `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: Sorry. Poorly worded on my part.  What I meant is that columns in the column list should either be in the GROUP BY clause or within some kind of aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    l.idlink
    , l.title
    , l.userid
    , u.iduser
    , u.username
    , c.idcomment
    , c.content

FROM Link AS l
    JOIN Users AS u ON u.iduser=l.userid
    JOIN Comment AS c ON c.linkid=l.idlink
```

Comment: he wants  group by u.username and the sum of comments per user

Comment: Or does he want the count of comments per link?  That is what Q3 would suggest.